# Trimming NSString

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trimming an `NSString` in the following way:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"X = (\\d+.\\d+), Y = (\\d+.\\d+), (%@)" options:0 error:NULL];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:txt.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [txt.text length])];
if (match) {
    NSRange firstHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *xString = [txt.text substringWithRange:firstHalfRange];
    NSRange secondHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:2];
    NSString *yString = [txt.text substringWithRange:secondHalfRange];
    NSRange thirdHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:3];
    NSString *colorString = [txt.text substringWithRange:thirdHalfRange];

    NSLog(@"X = %@, Y = %@, Color: %@", yString, xString, colorString);
}
```

The `NSString` looks like this:

```
@"this is the content. The content of this string may vary, as well as the length, and my include any characters, with numbers X = 295.000000, Y = 207.500000, TheWhite"
```

The part Y = 295.000000 X = 207.500000 remains always the same, apart from the X and Y numbers which may change, as well as the: TheWhite, which may become for e.g. TheBlack

Using this method I successfully extract the X and Y values, but not the final string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern ends with `(%@)`. I should end with `(.+)` instead.